# How to create two users : Buyers/Sellers in Django

Tags: django

I'm working on a project on how to create Two users : buyers/Sellers for Web using Django as Backend.
I've started the app "users"
I've read the Django Documentation about CustomUserModel
But Honestly don't know where to start from.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a Buyer might be a seller and a seller might be a Buyer.
There are some suggestions:

- Create your own application named users (This will help you full control User object in future).
- Set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings to `users.User`: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` As you defined.
- Define model Seller - OneToOne -> User: This contains seller's properties, Just create when access via `user.seller`
- Define model Buyer - OneToOne -> User: This contains buyer's properties, just create when access via `user.buyer`

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Your user's properties
    # Your user's method

    @property
    def buyer(self):
        try:
        return Buyer.objects.get(user=self)
        except Buyer.DoesNotExist:
            default_value_of_buyer = {}
            # Or define default value at model fields
            return Buyer.objects.create(user=self, **default_value_of_buyer)

    @property
    def seller(self):
        try:
            return Seller.objects.get(user=self)
    except Seller.DoesNotExist:
            default_value_of_seller = {}
            # Or define default value at model fields
        return Seller.objects.create(user=self, **default_value_of_seller)


class Buyer(models.Model):
    """
    You can add this to admin page to make some actions with Buyer
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buyer_profile')
    # Other properties of Buyer

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's Buyer profile" % self.user


class Seller(models.Model):
    """
    You can add this to admin page to make some actions with Seller
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='seller_profile')
    # Other properties of Seller

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's Seller profile" % self.user
```

Comment: I have done the first point. How can i define Seller Profile or Buyer Profile. For clarification, I want to have two types of users on the site. How do I implement the model?

Comment: I updated my solution, hope you will understand the idea.

Comment: When I create Superuser so as to access admin page, I get TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Comment: That's related to other issue, you might need to define `USERNAME_FIELD` field in your User model.

Comment: I have defined it

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard buddy look:
you create a model User
class User(models.Model):
.........
types = (('b','buyer'),('s','seller'))
user_type = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=types)

so every field has this argument called choices, it is a tuple that has tuples in it, every sub tuple is a choice and every choice has two elements the first one is what appears in the back end and the second element is what appears in the user interface, so 'b' is what appears in the back end and 'buyer' is what the user see in the form in the web site. Tell if that didn't work for you

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. Please dub it down a bit. Also, how do you create a model User class

Comment: Account(models.Model):

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account(models.Model):
    types = (
            ('B', 'BUYER' ),('S', 'SELLER')
            )
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=15)   
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=types)
```

TRY THIS AND THEN GO TO YOUR ADMIN PAGE AND YOU WILL UNDERSTAND EVERYTHING

Comment: When I create Superuser so as to access admin page, I get TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Comment: Any Suggestions on how to solve this Error. I haven't been able to solve it for a while.

Comment: @Shully add USERNAME_FIELDS = 'email or whatever you want to add i.e username or email for login and sign up'.